# How to get type information from possibly undefined variable and type parameter

Tags: typescript

I want to set a default value `defVal` based on the type of the incoming variable `val`. Many times the `val` will be undefined, so I can not use the JavaScript `typeof` operator. So `T` remains the only source of the type information. Of course the problem is that `T` is not known at runtime.

The `defVal` should be for example "" for string, 0 for number, etc...
Like `defVal = T is string ? "" : 0`

```
function getValue<T>(val?: T): T
{
  const defVal = "FIXME" as unknown as T // <---- get default value based on T
  return val ?? defVal;
}

const s = getValue<string>();   // want s === ""
const n = getValue<number>(2);  // want n === 2
```

Comment: Same sort of thing as in JavaScript https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/instanceof

Comment: When you pass `undefined` the function cannot possibly decide on a default value by itself. You'd need to pass an additional paremeter that describes the desired type, or pass the default value into the function and return it if `val` is `undefined`

Answer (score 0):

Based on my own experience and the comment from @MikeS., I think that although the Typescript is great for many many things, this is the simple case that it **can not** add any useful value to the code, because **it does not preserve the type information in the runtime**.

So it is more useful to use "old school" approach with separately named methods.

```
function getValueString(val?: string): string
{
  return val ?? "";
}

function getValueNumber(val?: number): number
{
  return val ?? 0
}

const s = getValueString();
const n = getValueNumber(2);

console.log(s, n);
```

Answer (score 0):

[TypeScript only exists at compile-time](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/basic-types.html#erased-types), so types can't be used to influence the runtime value that a function will return.

You can modify your function to use an [overload signature](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/functions.html#function-overloads), so that you can either infer from a value's type, or request a default type of value (taken from an object that you create). Here's an example of how to do that:

[TS Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?noUncheckedIndexedAccess=true&target=99&useUnknownInCatchVariables=true&exactOptionalPropertyTypes=true#code/MYewdgzgLgBAJgUwGYEMCuAbKEYF4YDeAUDDCgE7koCeAXDANoC6ZOaYA1mCAO5jMAaEjABGASwDmYsFHoAGMENIiQIDAhRh6qDBARKYYTBnpGMGA0YC2IhOXkGQIgFYJgswgF9WMAEpuQcjgAHgAFchAABzsoagBpBGoBGHYuXjAAPgNocmkJegByAoN2RCRpBDh6UuQKuCFPAG4iIiR2dzFwGAkEKAA1FAw0BBhggBUMgApY6IB1TShKwukkOwKASmqwMrrmtrAOrp7+weHRienqOYWlmAKVteSAN1OEejHNmDG99qhOsG6vQGQxG4xgCAAHottjgOIkQEgYDMEAj4Mh0FgIFNkfMZLcPvRkaiyhjsAwxkwfgc-kcga9ztirghcYsqjA4dRUUTESTMNgYAAfO4PcjFGAvEEAfne60IwjEiMu1zxcDwuHw9zAq1FsvIvTQ5ABEuGzVIeqgBoBvMxDBxNzglKInhaoEgagQADoMCAJJNjsDhpMChQqNQNutGjAAPRRlKcbh8Zj0ZhEV0Qd1en1+ukgoPiKQycORmOiSTSDwKVPgdPqTO+-2vPOqdSaIvR2Mqd2abSDPRVt21731nOBgpmDBtkvj0zGfs1z1D7MnXNjtA2NbrCPtwxr2z2GByOcZxcNldOVzuSex-ygIJhCLRcixBJJONpPgZegEZ1p49Z0+jjkeRXjAQFgPkMAAESQUeg7-iOCBBjU5RgJUIHIXUWw7KhcAutWf7Dsuo4iuh2y1DhsELvBRGIZq2pigATJuxaxgxlF1kuAa0SRyQFAAFgg5ggCBkECUJMG-nBhFcUGPGMPxgnemKBQ8IEGBwAUTDMduYESEmjCiYpICQckkGqeQ6mQUw7Enghslao88liUpvHmepmk+GmUDaSWeooHA4AYNQBnOcZpluXAVnJoZ4nhWpkXWSWHrJb0wAekQQA)

```ts
const defaults = {
  array: [] as unknown[],
  bigint: 0n,
  boolean: false,
  null: null,
  number: 0,
  object: {} as Record<PropertyKey, unknown>,
  string: '',
  undefined: undefined,
};

function getValue <T>(typeWanted: 'infer'): undefined;
function getValue <T>(typeWanted: 'infer', value: T): T;
function getValue <T extends keyof typeof defaults>(typeWanted: T): typeof defaults[T];
function getValue <T>(typeWanted: keyof typeof defaults | 'infer', value?: T) {
  if (typeWanted === 'infer') return value;
  return defaults[typeWanted];
}

console.log(getValue('array')); // unknown[]: []
console.log(getValue('bigint')); // bigint: 0n
console.log(getValue('boolean')); // boolean: false
console.log(getValue('null')); // null: null
console.log(getValue('number')); // number: 0
console.log(getValue('object')); // Record<PropertyKey, unknown>: {}
console.log(getValue('string')); // string: ""
console.log(getValue('undefined')); // undefined: undefined

console.log(getValue('infer')); // undefined
console.log(getValue('infer', 2)); // 2
console.log(getValue('infer', 'hello')); // "hello"
console.log(getValue('infer', ['hello', 'world'])); // string[]: ["hello", "world"]
console.log(getValue('infer', ['hello', 'world'] as const)); // readonly ["hello", "world"]: ["hello", "world"]
// ...etc.
```

Comment: I understand the principle here, but since "type erasure" the result is after all always the same - you have to "add something" or you will have no type info. Like in this case - you have to use default key. Or use "infer" but in fact those cases are not interesting because we already have value, since no default is necessary. It will be super useful if Typescript  will somehow add that type information in the code... but that is another story I suppose.

Comment: @TomHANAX Well, if you already have the value, then you don't need the function... It provides a standardized API for acquisition of value and type information for your program.